# Resize the parent div according the as nested child div is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am doing a custom form builder. I have an issue here.I want to resize the parent div when the child div is added. and it should also work in nested child div, so that all corresponding parents height should change according to child div
script

```
$('.innerElements').draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
    $('.dataContainer').sortable();

    $('.dataContainer, .innerElements').droppable({
        greedy: true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            debugger;
            var x = $(ui.draggable)
            if (!$(x).hasClass('temper')) {
                debugger;
                var y = x.clone();
                y.addClass('temper');
                var k = $(document.elementFromPoint(ui.position.left, ui.position.top))
                var w = k.width();
                var h = k.height();
                $(k).height(h + 50)
                $(k).width(w + 50)

                $(k).append($(y));
                $(y).children().sortable();
            }
        }
    });
```

'.innerElements' is the class  where the elements needed are dragged,and in droppable function i want the all parent div to enlarge according nested child div's are added

### html and javascript

```
<div class="eleContainer">
</div>
<div class="dataContainer">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.eleContainer').append('<div class="headElements"><b>Form Elements<b></div>')
    $('.eleContainer').append('<div class="subElements"></div>')

    $('.subElements').append('<h6>Container</h6>')
                     .append('<div class="contElements form"></div>')
                     .append('<h6>Form Elements</h6>')
                     .append('<div class="formElements" form></div>')

    $('.subElements').accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true })
    $('.contElements').append('<div class="innerElements header">Header</div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements container">Container</div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements footer">Footer</div>')

    $('.formElements').append('<div class="innerElements form_ele buttongroup">Button Group<br></div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements form_ele button">Button<br></div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements form_ele radioButton">Radio button<br></div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements form_ele checkbox">CheckBox<br></div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements form_ele text">Text<br></div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements form_ele label">Label<br></div>')
                      .append('<div class="innerElements form_ele forTexta">TextArea<br></div>')


    $('.header').append('<div class="headerdiv common"></div>')
    $('.container').append('<div class="containerdiv common"></div>')
    $('.footer').append('<div class="footerdiv common"></div>')

    $('.buttongroup').append('<button>Button1</button>')
                    .append('<button>Button2</button>')
                    .append('<button>Button3</button>')

    $('.button').append('<button>Button1</button>')

    $('.radioButton').append('<input type="radio" value="radio1" id="formradio" class="formradio"> radio1<br>')
                                          .append('<input type="radio" value="radio2" id="formradio" class="formradio">radio2<br>')
                                          .append('<input type="radio" value="radio3" id="formradio" class="formradio">radio3<br>')
                                          .append('<input type="radio" value="radio4" id="formradio" class="formradio">radio4<br>')

    $('.checkbox').append('<input type="checkbox" id="formcheck1" class="formcheck">checkbox1<br>')
                  .append('<input type="checkbox" id="formcheck2" class="formcheck">checkbox2<br>')
                  .append('<input type="checkbox" id="formcheck3" class="formcheck">checkbox3<br>')
                  .append('<input type="checkbox" id="formcheck4" class="formcheck">checkbox4<br>')

    $('.text').append('<input type="text" id="formtext" class="formtext">')

    $('.forTexta').append('<textarea>Include Text</textarea>')
```

The elements are appended to the div through javascript

Comment: So what is the issue? Could you post the html? A www.jsfiddle.net also helps people help you.

Comment: Can't you simply leave the height as `auto` so that it'll increase automatically…?

Comment: @TJ:IF i give heigth as auto; initially the dropppable container '.dataContainer' div height will be null so that only width will be shown and the droppable function will not occur.

Comment: use `min-height` to set a default height, when the height increase it'll expand automatically..

Comment: Did that fix the issue..? if not, please provide the css as well to reproduce the issue or a minimal demo...