# Javascript: can you automatically update the width of a parent's container after adding elements to it?

Tags: javascript, css, width, parent

I have a flexbox container with 3 boxes inside; it is column-oriented, it wraps and has a fixed height. There is a button which, when clicked, adds a new box to the container. Problem: the width of the parent/container, set to 'fit-content', doesn't update when the new child boxes are added. **Is there a way to automatically update the size of the parent element when adding child elements to it?** You can see if the parent's size was updated by looking at the border (and by confirming it later with DevTools).

You can see the site in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/AN90/pen/yLEPQPK

HTML code:

```
<button id="button-1">Button 1</button>        

<section class="boxes-container">
  <div class="boxes" id="box-1"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="box-2"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="box-3"></div>
</section>
```

CSS code:

```
button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.boxes-container{    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 548px;
    border: 4px solid #000;
}

.boxes {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(113, 255, 113);
    margin: 15px;
}
```

JS code:

```
let btn1 = document.getElementById('button-1')
let boxNr = 3
let boxesContainer = document.querySelector('.boxes-container')

btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let box = document.querySelector('.boxes:last-child')
    let duplicateBox = box.cloneNode(true)    
    boxNr++
    duplicateBox.id = `box-${boxNr}`
    boxesContainer.appendChild(duplicateBox)    
})
```

Here is a codepen with a solution reached through variables and inline-styling, which I think is not ideal: https://codepen.io/AN90/pen/OJEOaOb

Question was asked here but not really answered:
[Resize the parent div according the as nested child div is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029755/resize-the-parent-div-according-the-as-nested-child-div-is-added)

Thank you!

Comment: Something to note, if you add more elements just in the HTML to your boxes container it still doesn't put a border round all the boxes just the first 3. Might not be an issue with the width not updating on adding new boxes. Might be something wrong with the CSS and how it behaves once there are more than 3 boxes.

Comment: I think the border is dependent on the width value, isn't it?
As for the problem, it looks like CSS is static in its values, even if new elements are added as children of other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what the solution would be while using flexbox to achieve this, but I would like to recommend CSS grid to achieve this same (ish) visual effect.

```js
let btn1 = document.getElementById('button-1')
let boxNr = 3
let boxesContainer = document.querySelector('.boxes-container')

btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let box = document.querySelector('.boxes:last-child')
    let duplicateBox = box.cloneNode(true)    
    boxNr++
    duplicateBox.id = `box-${boxNr}`
    boxesContainer.appendChild(duplicateBox)    
})
```

```css
button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.boxes-container{    
    display: grid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 548px;
    width: fit-content;
    border: 4px solid #000;
    /* NEW */ grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); 
    /* NEW */ grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.boxes {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(113, 255, 113);
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button-1">Button 1</button>        

<section class="boxes-container">
  <div class="boxes" id="box-1"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="box-2"></div>
  <div class="boxes" id="box-3"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Great, with grid it worked! Thank you. Here's a codepen with your proposed solution:
https://codepen.io/AN90/pen/bGKaGbp